# OpenCV blocking my GTK interface

Tags: c++, opencv, gtk

I've coded a very simple GUI with GTK3, with three buttons:

- **Start**: calls OpenCV VideoCapture
- **Stop**: stops the VideoCapture
- **Quit**: destroys the window

The problem arises when I hit "Stop", the OpenCV process blocks the GUI and the command is executed after many seconds (typically, a minute).

this is my main:

```
bool stop = false;

static void start_webcam (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer   data)
{
    cout<<"Webcam On"<<endl;

    int err = 0;
    **err = opencv_webcam(); // this function loads the OpenCV Webcam**

    // troubles?
    if (err != 0)
    {
        cout<<"Unable to load the webcam. Error Code # "<<err<<endl;
    }
}

static void stop_webcam (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer  data)
{
    stop = true;
    cout<<"Webcam Off"<<endl;
}

int main (int   argc, char *argv[])
{

    // Widgets
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *grid;
    GtkWidget *button;

    // GTK Init
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "WEBCAM CONTROL PANEL");
    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);

    grid = gtk_grid_new ();

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), grid);

    /// START WEBCAM
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Start");
    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (start_webcam), NULL);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), button, 0, 0, 1, 1);

    /// STOP WEBCAM
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Stop");
    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (stop_webcam), NULL);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), button, 1, 0, 1, 1);


    /// QUIT
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Quit");
    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), button, 0, 1, 2, 1);


    /// GO!

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    gtk_main ();


    return 0;
}
```

I would like to set some high priority to the Quit button. I tried by setting the highest priority in my main by SetPriorityClass() in Windows, but I was unsuccessful.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

this is my openCV code:

```
extern bool stop;

int opencv_webcam()
{

    /// Various stuff
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::namedWindow("Webcam Session");

    /// Webcam Opening
    cv::VideoCapture clip(0);

    while(stop != true)
    {

        // frames extraction
        clip.grab();
        clip.retrieve(frame);

        // troubles?
        if ((frame.empty()==1))
        {
            // errore!
            return -1;
        }

        /// SHOW the frames
        cv::imshow("Webcam Session", frame);
        if (waitKey(30)>= 0)
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute the OpenCV code in a different thread?

Comment: Not yet. I would like to solve this issue by setting gtk properly...

Comment: Is the code you've shown the whole code? It appears that your "Stop" callback returns to the main loop immediately, which means that the GUI should keep running. Is there some other way for the control to get transferred to OpenCV code?

Comment: No, it isn't. 
My callback function sets stop to TRUE, and this is the exit condition of the while block inside OpenCV code. 
I will add more code in my main post.

Comment: This is for GTK# , but the main ideas are still valid for GTK+ on C code: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/responsive-applications/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK+ is **NOT** multithreaded. When one of your signal handlers is running, *all other GUI processing stops*. Your `opencv_webcam()` function is running on the GUI thread, and runs its main loop while processing the Start button signal. The reason why your Stop and Quit buttons aren't working is because they never get a chance to run (at least not until `opencv_webcam()` errors out).

I don't know what the appropriate solution is; I don't know enough about OpenCV to suggest a solution that lets you have stable timing while playing nice with GTK+. I know of two possibilities, though:

1. Doing all OpenCV processing in a `gdk_threads_add_idle()` callback (stable timing will be harder)
2. Running OpenCV on a different thread (you will need to communicate frame images across threads if you want to show them in your window)

You will need to search around and figure out what the best solution is. Try Googling for "gtk opencv" and seeing what you get.

Alternatively, if you're doing strict webcam work, you might want to look at [libcheese](https://developer.gnome.org/cheese/stable/libcheese.html), which is a GTK+ complement specifically intended for webcams.

---

As for button priorities, there's no signal prioritization that I know of. Given the diagnosis of your bug above, you should be able to see why prioritization wouldn't have helped anyway. In fact, I don't know of **any** GUI toolkit for any platform that has that ability. You should instead fix threading bugs that prevent the GUI from being snappy.